# ksh getopts unknown option Error

Tags: ksh, getopts

I am using getopts to get passed options to a ksh script but the options aren't being recognized by getopts.

Here is the options part of the usage string I give to getopts

```
#OPTIONS
USAGE+="[w:week?print the whole week]"
USAGE+="[b:before?print the month up to and including the requested day]"
USAGE+="[a:after?print the month starting from the requested day to the end of the month or week]"
USAGE+="[d:day]#[day:=$(date "+%d"|sed 's/^0*//')?requested day]{[1-31]}"
USAGE+="[m:month]#[month:=$(date "+%m"|sed 's/^0*//')?month of requested day]{[1-12]}"
USAGE+="[y:year]#[year:=$(date "+%Y")?year of requested day.]"
```

And here is my getopts block

```
while getopts "$USAGE" optchar
do
    echo $optchar
    case $optchar
    in
            w)      boolWEEK=true;
                    ;;

            b)      boolBEFORE=true;
                    ;;
            a)      boolAFTER=true;
                    ;;
            d)      day=$OPTARG
                    ;;
            m)      month=$OPTARG
                    ;;
            y)      year=$OPTARG
                    ;;
            esac
done
```

Here is the output of running the script with an option

```
$ ksh now.ksh -a
now.ksh: -a: unknown option
?
Usage: now.ksh [-wba] [-d day] [-m month] [-y year]
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the 
[ast getopts](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/man/man1/getopts.html) syntax.

I got this working by adding `[-]` to the front of the USAGE string:

```
USAGE+="[-][w:week?print the whole week]"
```

Perhaps the `[-]` is required to resolve any ambiguity in the option string.